# Using ClientSession::Run and ClientSession:FeedType in tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow and machine learning, I'm attempting to use the C++ API to make a single layer fully connected neural network to recognize digits from the MNIST database.

In the official documentation, this is the use case:

```
Status Run(
  const FeedType & inputs,
  const std::vector< Output > & fetch_outputs,
  std::vector< Tensor > *outputs
) const
```

where FeedType is `std::unordered_map< Output, Input::Initializer, OutputHash > FeedType`.

I need to feed two data sets: the image ([][784]) and the expected result ([][10]) in order to train it.

Can someone give me an example of how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution looking in the source code of the API: feeding the data should look like this:

```
ClientSession::FeedType feed;
Tensor m_tensor(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({length}));
//length is an int representing the dimension of the tensor
for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++){
     data[i] = m[i]; //m is where your feed data is
}
feed.insert({x, m_tensor}); //x is a placeholder
```

However, this is a solution that compiles, as I'm still stuck on a few ends and I've yet to test if it also works as intended. I apologize for the poor formatting.

Comment: I've managed to compile and run it, this solution works, although I can't guarantee it's the best way to do this.